# Need help joining 2 edges

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, faces, edges

I need to close this object, as you can see on the pictures there is a space between the walls, I need to join the edges in a triangular shape, keeping the same wall orientation. I hope you understand me, thanks for this awesome forum, I'm using blender 2.70.

[image]

[image]

Stay good!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is **merge** the 2 edges. To accomplish this:
Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter edit mode, then <kbd>1</kbd> to switch to vertex select.
Now, click one of the vertices of the side you want to join, then holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, press the adjacent vertex of the other wall. This will select both vertices.
Now, to merge the vertices, press <kbd>M</kbd> and choose the option that best suits you:

- Merge at first. This moves the second vertex you selected to the first one you selected, and makes them into 1 vertex.
- Merge at last. This moves the first vertex you selected to the second one you selected, and makes them into 1 vertex.
- Merge at center. This moves both vertices to the spot directly between each prior location.

Now, repeat with the other 2 vertices.

Comment: Thank you very much!!, I'm gonna try it right know, I'm sure that's what I need. Thanks!!!

Comment: worked perfectly :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad to be of use!

Comment: I don't think any of the options presented here will correctly preserve wall orientation, which I interpreted as the OP intention

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos this is the closest you can get without adding a 4th wall. Also, OP said that it worked. Had OP said that the wall orientation was unsatisfactory, I would edit my response to help further.